# How to select the max date with additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following data base structure (its just a demo structure):

```
order:
| id | orderedat |

order_item:
| id | id_order | id_article | price | currency |
```

What I want to get is the latest order price of each article:

```
| id_article | orderedat | price | currency |
```

I wrote this statement to achive the goal:

```
WITH "last_ordered" AS (   
  SELECT "oi"."id_article", "oi"."id" as "id_oi", MAX("o"."orderedat")   
  FROM "order" "o", "order_item" "oi"   
  WHERE ("oi"."id_order" = "o"."id")            
  GROUP BY "oi"."id", "oi"."id_id_article"    
)   
SELECT "oi"."id_article", "o"."orderedat", "oi"."price", "oi"."currency"   
FROM "order_item" "oi"   
INNER JOIN "last_ordered" ON ("oi"."id" = "last_ordered"."id_oi")   
INNER JOIN "order" "o" ON ("oi"."id_order" = "o"."id")
```

However, the group by is wrong, as it returns one line for each order_item the article is linked to. On the other hand column "oi.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause. I don't know how to solve this issue. Can someone help me please?

Maybe there is another solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Join both tables and then start from the article and get the max(orderedat) - in the cte - group by article.  Then link them all to another joined set of order and order_item linking on the article and the max date.  Remember to group on the final result too, as there may be duplicate items ordered on the same day (maybe refer to MAX(Order.ID), as there could be duplicated ones sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct on (id_article)
    id_article, orderedat, price, currency
from
    order o
    inner join
    order_item oi on o.id = oi.id_order
order by id_article, orderedat desc
```

Check [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH "last_ordered" AS (   
  SELECT "o".*,"oi".*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "oi"."id_id_article" ORDER BY "o"."orderedat" DESC) as Rnum 
  FROM "order" "o"
  INNER JOIN "order_item" "oi"   
  ON "oi"."id_order" = "o"."id"            

) 

SELECT * FROM  last_ordered
WHERE Rnum =1
```